# "Microsoft Office Word 2003 has not been installed for the current user." error in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word

I started having problems with Office 2003 on my Windows XP laptop. I decided to reninstall it. Now, when I launch the Office Word application, I get the following error message:

> Microsoft Office Word has not been installed for the current user. Please run setup to install the application.

I have tried to reinstall but the problem persists. There is only one account on this computer and it is the administrator. I have tried to edit the registery and give everyone full permissions on all of the office files. It did not work.

I have also tried to enter in safe mode and edit the opa11.dat file's security settings, but the security tab was not present.

If anyone has any ideas, please reply.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your machine with an updated AV in safe mode and then log on and uninstall the office and also delete the remaining folder and files and then delete all another accounts and let admin remains, then try to reinstall the office again. I don't know it can help or not but it was the only instant idea that was in my mind.